# Mann-Whitney U test pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| ddos_date|count_before|ColumnIndex|
+----------+------------+-----------+
|2017-12-30|          88|          0|
|2017-12-30|         129|          1|
|2017-12-30|          98|          2|
|2017-12-30|          90|          3|
|2017-12-30|          80|          4|
|2017-12-30|          84|          5|
|2017-12-30|         158|          6|
|2018-01-01|          98|          7|
|2018-01-01|          90|          8|
|2018-01-01|          80|          9|
|2018-01-01|          84|         10|
|2018-01-01|         158|         11|
|2018-01-01|          74|         12|
|2018-01-01|         162|         13|
+----------+------------+-----------+

+----------+-----------+-----------+
| ddos_date|count_after|ColumnIndex|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|2017-12-30|         60|          0|
|2017-12-30|        117|          1|
|2017-12-30|        167|          2|
|2017-12-30|         88|          3|
|2017-12-30|        158|          4|
|2017-12-30|         74|          5|
|2017-12-30|        162|          6|
|2017-12-30|        144|          7|
|2018-01-01|        167|          8|
|2018-01-01|         88|          9|
|2018-01-01|        129|         10|
|2018-01-01|         98|         11|
|2018-01-01|        162|         12|
|2018-01-01|        144|         13|
|2018-01-01|        116|         14|
|2018-01-01|         82|         15|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I joined these dataframes and the result is shown below:

```
+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
|count_before|      date|count_after|      date|
+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
|          88|2017-12-30|         60|2017-12-30|
|          98|2018-01-01|        144|2017-12-30|
|         158|2017-12-30|        162|2017-12-30|
|          80|2018-01-01|         88|2018-01-01|
|          84|2017-12-30|         74|2017-12-30|
|         129|2017-12-30|        117|2017-12-30|
|          84|2018-01-01|        129|2018-01-01|
|          90|2017-12-30|         88|2017-12-30|
|          74|2018-01-01|        162|2018-01-01|
|          90|2018-01-01|        167|2018-01-01|
|         158|2018-01-01|         98|2018-01-01|
|          98|2017-12-30|        167|2017-12-30|
|          80|2017-12-30|        158|2017-12-30|
|         162|2018-01-01|        144|2018-01-01|
|        null|      null|        116|2018-01-01|
|        null|      null|         82|2018-01-01|
+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

The aim is to groupby 'date' and perform mann-whitney test on two samples of different size: count_before and count_after.

Please help.

further reference on dataframes are appended to a list and then merged into a single dataframe:

```
df1_list = []
df2_list = []

for d in date_list:
    df1, df2 = hdf(df, d)
    
    df1_list.append(df1)
    df2_list.append(df2)
    

df1 = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df1_list)
df2 = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df2_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the mann-whitney U test, but here's my attempt to do it. Let me know if it's what you're trying to calculate. I used the function from [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html).

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df1.join(
    df2, ['ddos_date', 'ColumnIndex']
).drop('ColumnIndex').groupBy('ddos_date').agg(
    F.collect_list(F.array('count_before', 'count_after')).alias('arr')
).withColumn(
    'u_value', 
    F.udf(
        lambda arr:
            [float(j) for j in mannwhitneyu([i[0] for i in arr], [i[1] for i in arr])],
        'array<float>'
    )('arr')
)

result.show(truncate=False)
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|ddos_date |arr                                                                         |u_value           |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|2018-01-01|[[90, 167], [80, 88], [84, 129], [158, 98], [74, 162], [162, 144]]          |[9.5, 0.09969863] |
|2017-12-30|[[88, 60], [129, 117], [98, 167], [90, 88], [80, 158], [84, 74], [158, 162]]|[21.0, 0.35042578]|
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: glad to get your help! I have one doubt : mannwhitneyu returns two values (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html). how can I get that?

Comment: @SameekshaSohal see edited answer... sorry I thought you only want U.

Comment: the code works just fine, I need to look how mann-whitney handles different sample sizes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am bit confused. sorry if the questions seems vague. so this script compares all the values of count_before with all the values of count_after? there are some values that are missing in the result, is it because of the different sample size?

Comment: Yes, because I think the U value requires 1-to-1 pairing

Comment: follow up question: when the two dfs are joined on `ColumnIndex` and  `ddos_date`, it drops the records where `ColumnIndex` and  `ddos_date` are not equal which leads to dropping the required values from `ddos_date`.

Comment: use left join if you want to keep the records

Comment: hi again,sorry for bringing up silly doubts but kindly help if you can. so basically I am missing out onto some dates, which are actually present in both `df1` and `df2`. but when I compute `result`, I don't see that.

Comment: for more reference: i have added the snippet under 'further reference' in the question above

Comment: sorry but I can't figure out what's wrong - there's not enough information

Comment: Isn't  the F.collect_list() function collecting all the data into driver machine. Hence it is not longer distributed any more? Or am I missing out any point